# Changing QTY from the Catalog Page

Tags: product, catalog, quantity

You used to be able to change the quantities of products without having to actually open a new page for the specific SKU. You could do it right from the catalog page where it shows all your SKUs.

Either my browser is screwy, or this is no longer possible.

Anyone know a fix for this?`

Comment: Are you saying change qty in admin product or while adding to the cart? Bit of confusion, could you add more info please.

Comment: No basically you used to be able to change the quantity in magento admin> catalog . When you are on the catalog page, and there are all your SKU's, under the QTY column you could edit quantities from there (versus opening each sku in a new window). No more on my end.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Magento doesn't come with this feature by default. You cannot edit any of product's data in `product grid` which you are calling as `admin product catalog page`. In fact in magento grid editing is not available till 1.9.x.x version, not sure about magento 2.

**What's the solution?**

This can be done though thorough third party extensions. If you would like to develop your own, you can otherwise there are already built extensions in the market which comes with really nice features.

**Available Extensions**

1. https://amasty.com/extended-product-grid-with-editor.html
2. https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/admin-product-grid.html
3. etc.

**If you would like to built your own**

This is very good example: https://www.atwix.com/magento/inline-editing-in-magento-backend-grids/